# What is the convention in referring to a non-overridden superclass method from within the subclass?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Which of these is preferred? I believe they are identical in outcome.

```
self.inheritedMethodName(arguments)
```

Or:

```
ParentClass.inheritedMethodName(self, arguments)
```

I am aware there is also:

```
super().inheritedMethodName(arguments)
```

But my understanding is that this is discouraged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is definitely preferred.  It's a basic feature of Python that `instance.method(...)` is translated into `Class.method(instance, ...)`.  There is rarely a need to use the second form explicitly, and it will only confuse people reading your code, since they'll wonder why you did it.

More generally, why would you be calling a method differently depending on whether you override it or not?  In general, you just call the method on an object, and let the object (including its class hierarchy) decide which implementation should be called.  You would only typically use the third form (with `super`) from within a method to explicitly call the superclass version of that same method.

Comment: But when you HAVE overridden a method, and wish to call the super as part of the overridden method, *then* you should use the second syntax?

Comment: @Aerovistae: No, in that case you should use `super`.

Comment: I have read often that super() is best saved for cases when multiple inheritance gets involved.

Comment: @Aerovistae: Multiple inheritance is when `super` provides the most headache-savings, but there's no real reason not to use it even with single inheritance.

Comment: BrenBarn is totally right ... that said Im still guilty of using the `Superclass.overridden(self,*args)` method far more than I should